# Android Studio Unable to Find Genymotion Device

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

Been trying to load a test Android app onto my Genymotion VM for awhile now. My issue is, I have been unable to get the Genymotion device to show up in the "connected devices", even though the device shows up in the Android Studio Genymotion plugin.

These are my depencies:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
compile files('libs/temboo-android-sdk-core-2.12.0.jar')
compile files('libs/Google-2.12.0.jar')
```

The Genymotion plugin was able to find my two devices:

[image]

However, according to Android Studio, there are still no connected devices:

[image]

Even the logs appear to show that the app was loaded, however, when I opened Genymotion, I am unable to find my application:

[image]

I've tried using `Run`, `Debug`, and more, but was just unable to get my application onto my Genymotion VM.

Comment: You would have to do the port forwarding on the gennymotion for it to be detected.

adb connect XXX.XXX.XXX:PORT

Comment: @cafebabe1991Is it possible to do this within the GUI of Android Studio?

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to help you out with the forwarding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do the port forwarding on the gennymotion for it to be detected.

```
adb connect XXX.XXX.XXX:PORT
```

[Discussion about it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genymotion-users/ov5ANqGf3DI)

Forwarding can be done for gennymotion...
Here's a [link](http://paulsdevworld.blogspot.in/2013/06/make-android-studio-work-with-androvm.html)

> Explantion about this forwarding thing...

[image: The forwarding port number]

See this above image, it has the host port(Operating system) and the Guest port(Its the Genny motion).So we tell to the Virtual box to forward all connections of Genny's internal port to the OS port.

Comment: I have the Android SDK installed, however, cannot use the `adb` command. Using `brew install android-sdk` right now.

Comment: The `XXX.XXX.XXX:PORT` is the one that shows up in the plugin IP address within Android Studio right?

Comment: Thats the ip of your VM (Genny's)

Comment: Hm, So this is what I did: `$ adb connect 192.168.58.101`, then the output I have is `already connected to 192.168.58.101:5555`

Comment: I also followed the instructions in your page to connect using 127.0.0.1 after setting up port forwarding in Adapter 2: http://puu.sh/jT2WT/c52d2ab560.png and http://puu.sh/jT2Y6/5b7987ad77.png No luck..

Comment: try adb kill-server 
then 
adb connect <ip>:port

then 
adb devices

Comment: Thank you. THis worked. Apparently I also didn't have the SDK Platform tools installed, which I did so under the Tools tab. Android programming is always so aggrevating.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Great....Do accept if it worked for you and it'll help others in future..