# Cannot Run App On Genymotion Emulator From Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

My OS is Windows 7 Pro, and I installed Android Studio 2.1, which is the latest version at the moment, and I followed the instruction from this [video tutoril](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWZ2rVFOQWw) to install and setup Genymotion, I did each step exactly as the video shows, but in the end I cannot run my app on the virtual device created in Genymotion(but in the video, it works fine), what I got is:

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, the emulator on the left is started from the Geny plugin in AS, and the right dialog is what I got after I click Run button, it seems that the virtual device is not recognized by AS.

The Event Log is:

> 11:18:01 PM error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot
>   bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
>   11:18:02 PM could not read ok from ADB Server 11:18:02 PM * failed to
>   start daemon * 11:18:02 PM error: cannot connect to daemon 11:18:02 PM
>   'C:\Users\Vincent\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server'
>   failed -- run manually if necessary

**What I have tried so far:**

Firstly, I found this post: [Android Studio Unable to Find Genymotion Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290210/android-studio-unable-to-find-genymotion-device), which gives a link of a discussion in google forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genymotion-users/ov5ANqGf3DI.

From the discussion, one named Jordan said that two things need to be done: "bridged adapter" and "port forwarding". But in the setting panel of VirtualBox on my PC, what I found is:

[image]

If I set Adapter2 as bridged adapter, the 'Port Forwarding' button will be disabled. So I cannot do both things at the same time. I tried bridged adapter first, it didn't work, and then I set it back to NAT as default, added the port forwarding rule, ran the adb command as explained in that post.

[image]

BTW, the approach they told to find the ip address didnt work for me, I could not install play store into that virtual device, so I figured out the virtual device's ip address from VirtualBox.

Anyway, neither of them works so far.

Secondly, I tried the approach in this blog: http://scrumsofanarchy.com/adb-over-wi-fi-with-genymotion-android-emulator/, and ended up with nothing, coz basically I cannot install any app into the virtual device.

Thirdly, I tried the approach in this post as well: [android studio - emulator doesn't work and genymotion doesn't get recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664012/android-studio-emulator-doesnt-work-and-genymotion-doesnt-get-recognized). My Genymotion is using the SDK installed by AS now, but that doesnt fix the issue.

I am running out of options now, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just install GPU Debugging Tools 3.1 in Android SDK Mangaer ;-)